# Make goimports NOT scan files within vendor

Tags: go

I want to setup a CI system that it fails when code is not properly formatted according to `goimports`.

How I list my dirs:

```
go list -f {{.Dir}} ./...
/Users/felix/gocode/src/github.com/XXXX/YYY
/Users/felix/gocode/src/github.com/XXXX/YYY/cmd/foo
/Users/felix/gocode/src/github.com/XXXX/YYY/cmd/dev
/Users/felix/gocode/src/github.com/XXXX/YYY/pkg/monitoring/top
```

How I run `goimports` in the end:

```
goimports -l $(go list -f {{.Dir}} ./...)
/Users/felix/gocode/src/github.com/XXX/YYY/config.go
/Users/felix/gocode/src/github.com/XXX/YYY/raid_test.go
/Users/felix/gocode/src/github.com/XXX/YYY/vendor/github.com/shirou/gopsutil/disk/disk_freebsd.go
/Users/felix/gocode/src/github.com/XXX/YYY/vendor/github.com/shirou/gopsutil/disk/disk_linux.go
/Users/felix/gocode/src/github.com/XXX/YYY/vendor/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal/util_solaris.go
```

As you can see it also lists files within `vendor`. The execution also takes quite some time so I guess it's really checking all the files.
I really just care about the files outside `vendor`.

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47529611/goimports-needs-to-ignore-vendor-package Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you use <1.9 Go version. Since 1.9 ./... shouldn't match vendor directory. See https://golang.org/doc/go1.9#vendor-dotdotdot.